# Vue.js difference between v-model and :value when freezing objects in arrays and then trying to modify them

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

So I have a table with rows, in the row I have a annotation field that needs to be editable.

The objects that are fetched from the db get frozen before they are stored in the array. This was a decision made to decrease memory bloating that was noticed on many pages that fetch data tables with many rows.

ex.

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { Object.freeze(response.data[i]); }
this.recordProductsList = this.recordProductsList.concat(response.data);
```

If I try and modify the field, I get an error saying "Error: can't modify a read only field"

And I understand this, because I've frozen that object!

But then I modify the element from a v-model to a :value and it seems to work fine with no errors and it looks like it saved it fine and fetches it fine and updates fine!

Why? What's the difference here and should I be concerned for something in the future I'm not understanding?

```html
<td>
  <v-text-field v-model="props.item.productAnnotationText" @input='inputAnnotation($event, props.item.id)' :disabled="!editMode" color="primary">
  </v-text-field>
</td>


to

<td>
  <v-text-field :value="props.item.productAnnotationText" @input='inputAnnotation($event, props.item.id)' :disabled="!editMode" color="primary">
  </v-text-field>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `v-model`:

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="props.item.productAnnotationText"
>
```

is a shorthand for:

```
<v-text-field
    :value="props.item.productAnnotationText"
    @input="props.item.productAnnotationText = $event"
>
```

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

As the object `props.item` is frozen the event listener will fail, as you've observed.

When you change it to use just `:value` you won't get that `input` listener, so no modification of the object is attempted.

However, that doesn't stop the `input` event firing. You have your own listener, `inputAnnotation`, and that should be called just fine. It won't be able to modify the properties of `props.item` either but it sounds like that isn't something you need.

The key thing to appreciate is that the object `props.item` will now be out of date and still contains the old value. That may not be immediately apparent but it could come back to be a problem if that value is used subsequently.

Based on what you've said it sounds like you save the data to the server and then refetch the updated data. In that case you'll likely be throwing away the original frozen object `props.item` and replacing it with an entirely new object to represent that same row. So long as nothing else is clinging on to a reference to that original object that should mean that all your data is now up to date.